# How to make a clamp for this motor to move it in two directions?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, applied-mechanics, mechanisms, mechanical

I'm working on a disc brake balancing machine, as shown below this is a belt pulley drive and for alignment purposes I want motor to be able to move *vertically as well as inwards outwards* (to tighten the belt). Is there any clamp/adjuster design to achieve this?
[image: Disk brake balancing machine]

Comment: What have you found so far?

Comment: I found to use a slotted hole but this can just translate in one direction.

Comment: Can the pulley on the motor slide up and down? If so, how much? That would solve one direction of adjustment very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dovetail guide for the vertical movement and place the motor on it using elevating screws for the horizontal movement.

[image: Dovetail guide]

If you place the bottom plate of the contraption above (picture [source](https://www.norelem.de/xs_db/BILD_DB/2/www/750/21030.jpg)) on the box and use the threaded holes on the top plate to mount the motor, you can move the motor up or down. Use screws in the holes at the side of the upper plate to adjust friction and lock both in one position.

[image]

Next, use something like the screws above (picture [source](https://img0.fastenal.com/productimages/3430206.jpg)) to fix the motor to the upper plate.

Comment: The dovetail guide Looks to be a very expensive solution...

Answer (score 0):

For vertical movement you could use a round guide and a tight fit rubber ring inside the holder to enable movement when you want to move it but for friction to keep it in place when you want to keep it still.
For horozontal movement you could use scissor mechanism with screw which could control movement and act as a brake.